# Can't create a distribution provisioning profile in iOS Dev Center

Tags: ios, distribution

My problem is, that i can't create a distribution provisioning profile in the iOS Dev Center.

1. I created a new App in the iOS Dev Center
2. I programmed the app
3. I built the app with an existing distribution provisioning profile from an other app
4. I created the App in the iTunes Connect Center and set it ready for upload
5. When uploading the Application with the Application Loader, it said, that the bundle identifiers (from the iTunesConnect App and the uploaded App) don't match
6. I wanted to create now the correct distribution prov. profile in the iOS Dev Center and build the app using the right bundle identifier and the right distribution prov. profile, but I couldn't create the distr. pov. profile

I was able to create the dev. prov profile for the same app, but not the distr.

When I want to create the profile it always says:

> Apple Developer Program
>
> Big Warning
>
> We are unable to process your request.
>
> Please go back to the previous page, or quit your browser and try your request again.
>   If you require assistance, please contact Apple Developer Support.

Does it have to do something with mydistribution certificate? It will expire in 32 days.
Or is there an other problem, i'm currently facing?

I hope, you can help me in this case!

Thanks,
Br
Nic

PS: regarding to that problem [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079419/problem-with-creating-distribution-provisioning-profile), i hope it will fix my problem

Comment: Apple updated the license agreement yesterday. You might need to agree to it again in itunes connect before you can do anything.

Comment: Thanks, i just forgot to agree to that latest iOS Paid Applications Agreement. But it didn't solve the problem event after agreeing that. Do you know anything else i can do? Thanks alot

Comment: Thats weird, i can create an AdHoc Prov Profile but no Distribution.

Comment: i'm also having the same problem. did apple disabled it for today?!?

Comment: I didn't get any response from apple till now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same trouble. I called Developer Support and they told me that the systems where being overwelhemed by the iOS5 downloads.

So they had me email the Provisioning team. Still have not heard anything back from them. But it appears to be affecting just about everyone, if not everyone.

Comment: I have tried colbeerhey's suggesting and did not seem to do anything for me. I have several different accounts for different products and they are all having the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Log into the development portal as the agent
2. Accept the new license agreement
3. Goto provisioning section and re-enable your provisioning profile
4. Refresh provisioning profiles in Xcode organizer